# Angular UI Boostrap: how to close the modal without a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to AngularJS, and were just going through Angular UI Modal described in: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.

I want to create a simple modal that have just only one button to close the modal. How to do this without create a separate controller for the modal? Is there a script for `ng-click` event in the modal template to do the job? Such as `this.close()`...

What I want to achieve look like this:

Template:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3>Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 <h4>Just something random here</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="this.close()">OK</button>
</div>
```

Page controller:

```
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: "modalContent.html",
      // it's so simple so that I don't want a separate controller
      //controller: "ModalContentCtrl",
      size: '',
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    });
  };
```

Comment: `controller` can be a function also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal):

> The scope associated with modal's content is augmented with:
>
> $close(result) (Type: function) - A method that can be used to close a
>   modal, passing a result.
>
> $dismiss(reason) (Type: function) - A method that can be used to
>   dismiss a modal, passing a reason.
>
> **Those methods make it easy to close a modal window without a need to create a dedicated controller.**

So this works:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3>Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 <h4>Just something random here</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()">OK</button>
</div>
```